# HTTP request does not contain valid JSON data - testing code for azure function

Tags: python, json, azure-functions

I've been creating a power app that sends to a function app that connects to Snowflake to retreive, insert and update a table. The Get function works fine, but I can't get the Update working. This should be tied to a form, but I need to verify it connects and will update before throwing in a whole other hurdle (the form). No matter what i try, i continue to the get the same error: HTTP request does not contain valid JSON data. I've been entering the updated data manuallly but am not entirely sure i'm entering it in the right place - so can't be sure if my problem is my testing or in the code. I am admittedly out of my league here - if someone could just tell me how I can test this properly, where I should enter my updates, I would be incredibly grateful.

tutorial i've been working from: https://medium.com/@onepoint.au/how-to-connect-microsoft-powerapps-to-snowflake-8c6db40931a3

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import snowflake.connector
import simplejson as json

func.HttpResponse.mimetype = 'application/json'
func.HttpResponse.charset = 'utf-8'

def get_connection():
    return snowflake.connector.connect(user='user@domain.com', password='password', 
account='account.account.azure', warehouse='WAREHOUSE_NAME')
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logger = logging.getLogger('azure')
    logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.') 
    ctx = get_connection()
    cursor = ctx.cursor()
    data = req.get_json()
    logging.info(data)
    table = req.params.get('table')
    schema = req.params.get('schema')
    if schema and table and ctx:
        logging.info(table)
        cursor = ctx.cursor()
        data = req.get_json()
        try:
            i=0
            while (i < len(data)):
                columns = []
                values = []
            if table == "TABLENAME": 
                for key in data [i].keys():
                    columns.append(key)
                    values.append(data[i][key]) 
                    data_iterator = 0
                    query = "UPDATE DATABASE.{}.TABLENAME SET".format(schema) 
                    while data_iterator < len(data[i].keys()):
                        query += f"{columns[data_iterator]} = '{values[data_iterator]}'"
                    data_iterator += 1
                    if(data_iterator == len(data[i].keys())):
                        query += "WHERE ID = " + f"{data[i]['ID']}"
                    else:
                        query += ", "
                        logging.info(query)
                        cursor.execute(query)
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        ctx.close()
        response = {"Message": "Request succeeded", "Status Code": 200}
        return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(response))
else:
    response = {"Message": "Request failed", "Status Code": 400}
    return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(response))
```